# how to set fill opacity in tkinter python gui?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter, alpha-transparency

I am trying to draw a circle on top of another rectangle. and i want to fill circle with some color and opacity so that below rectangle is somewhat visible. now i can't able to find how to do it using tkinter python module.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which widget are you using to draw these circles? A `canvas`?

Comment: yes canvas.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2, fill="")

Comment: look into using the `stipple` option in your `create_oval` call

Comment: That will work for me. but is there any other way to get more smooth or precise opacity option.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to use RGBA values for tkinter `canvas` items and as far as I know, there is no way other than to use the `stipple` option.

Comment: but stipple is not working for oval.